# PHP dividir uma variavel separada por "|" e trazer todos resultados que não são vazios

Tags: php

Tenho uma variavel que são as metragens das unidades do prédio e cada unidade é separada por `"|"` e que pode ter até 4 unidades, ex: `35|41|50|12`.
Mas nem sempre tem 4 unidades, ex: `41|50||`

Aí preciso "quebrar" essa variavel em variaveis individuais e pensei em fazer com explode:

```
$unidades = $row->fotos;
$unidades = explode("|", $unidades);
$un0 = $unidades[0];
$un1 = $unidades[1];
$un2 = $unidades[2];
$un3 = $unidades[3];
```

O problema nesse caso é que daí ele traz as $fotos[] vazias tbm.

Como posso fazer para trazer apenas as que tem algum valor? E também consiga pegar o maior e menor valor?

Em resumo o que preciso é que pegue o valor `35|41|50|12` por exemplo e mostre o menor e maior valor, algo como:
echo $menorvalor.' à '.$maiorvalor.'

Answer (score 1):

Você pode filtrar os valores com a função [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-filter.php) e s funções [min()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.min.php) e [max()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.max.php), para os valores específicos.

Ex:

```
$unidades = $row->fotos;
$unidades = explode("|", $unidades);

$unidades = array_filter($unidades, 'strlen');
```

Para pegar o menor valor.

```
$menorvalor = min($unidades);
```

Para pegar o maior valor

```
$maiorvalor = max($unidades);
```

Comment: legal, vou tentar aqui

Answer (score 0):

Outro jeito é você verificar se os valores foram todos recebidos para só depois colocar no vetor

```
<?php
    $unit = $_GET['unit'];
    $unidades = explode("|", $unit);
    $units = array();



    foreach ($unidades as $key => $val) {

        if( !empty( $val ) ){
            echo "Unidades Rec[" . $key . "] = " . $val . "<br>";
            $units[] = $val;
        }

    }
    sort($units);


    echo "Unidades: ".$menorvalor = min($units)." a ".$maiorvalor = max($units);



?>
```